# PHP Array Explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am imploding data inside of an array, called the following:

```
["Levels_SanctionLevel_array"]=>
string(14) "IR01,IR02,IR03"
```

I need to explode this data and input each value as a row inside of mysql. Such as

```
pri_id   value
---------------
01       IR01
02       IR02
03       IR04
```

Now where I am getting stuck is this:
The array listed above could have 1 value, 3 values (right now I am showing three values) or 5 values, and I dont want to input  NULL values inside of my database. 
Appreciate any guidance anyone can share...

Comment: Hi,

You should do a test to check if there is only one or more values in your array. If it is more than that you could use explode with "," as delimitor and create a temp array to insert in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop works correctly, but has the drawback of making multiple queries to the database:

```
$str = "IR01,IR02,IR03";
$vals = explode(',', $str);
foreach ($vals AS $value) {
  // insert into database
}
```

As DB operations are a more significant bottleneck than building a query in PHP, I would opt to generate the SQL code for a single query as follows:

```
$str = "IR01,IR02,IR03";
$vals = explode(',', $str);

$query = 'INSERT INTO my_data VALUES ';

foreach ($vals as $value) {
 $query .= "('', '".$value."'),";
}

$query = rtrim($query, ',');

// insert into database
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = explode(',',$your_string);
foreach ($data AS $value) {
  // INSERT INTO DB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an iterator over the array to construct the sql query?  That way you will only insert as many elements as you have in the array.

Like the answer above.  I think we were answering at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your major array is `$data`:

```
foreach ($data as $values)
{
    $value = explode(",", $values);

    foreach ($value as $v)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table(value) VALUES('$v')";
    }
}
```